# Mysql v5.1/RHEL6 dump to MariaDB v10.3/RHEL7 restore process

Tags: mysql, mariadb, migration, redhat

I am moving a number of databases from a MySQL 5.1 RHEL6 server to a MariaDB 10.3 RHEL7 server. Do I need to run mysql_update after doing the dump/restore of each DB, or is that just for system tables being updated in-place (same server)? Of course I am not dumping system tables, but will dump the GRANTS and restore those. We do not use views or triggers, but do use stored procedures, so I will use --routines in the dump command (and --extended-insert=true --compact --skip-add-locks). The largest DB by far is about 10GB (12m records across 10 tables); most are under 500MB.

Any advice/warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend running mysql_upgrade [once per server](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mysql-to-mariadb/).

While you have taken steps to avoid some of the complexities of system tables, mysql_upgrade helps cover some of other automated fixes that pop up from time to time.

Overall the size of the database is quite small and worth testing up front.

Obviously running RHEL6 don't mind end of life products, but why not jump to RHEL8 as RHEL7 is EOL in about 2 months?

Comment: Thanks; I'm in a large corporate environment with controlled access to available repos; RHEL8 not available yet.  RHEL7 is at least much later than RHEL6.  Since we will be moving one DB at a time over months, can you run the update process on a per DB basis?

Comment: mysql_upgrade is idpotent, running subsequent times is harmess. As you are probably migrating subsequent (all) database in a logical mysqldump form then mysql_update isn't required as its written around ensuring in place update is correct.

Comment: Thanks, danblack!